# Angular digest loop

Tags: angularjs, infinite-loop, digest

I have a problem with my app because it creates infinite loop cycle when trying to generate form. My form is generated based on json (example in code). Problem occurs only when i go to another step and go back to form. I have no idea what causes that problem because it only happens when state is loaded for the second time. Is it possible that angular keep watchers that was created in previous state and it just overlaps each other?

Whole idea about this app is that you have form definition in "form" section, then there is a "schema" which define each model element and at the end there is a "model" which stores all variables.

```
<schema-form
    data-name     = "theemployeeform"
    data-schema   = "$ctrl.json.all_fields.schema"
    data-form     = "$ctrl.json.all_fields.form"
    data-model    = "$ctrl.json.model">
</schema-form>
```

To see error please open chrome inspector and:
Home -> Form -> Home -> Form
`Error: [$rootScope:infdig]`

[App example on Plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/nkdzwLuEO0RauZT1jpOJ?p=preview](https://plnkr.co/edit/nkdzwLuEO0RauZT1jpOJ?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

See if you have created a watch of your own on the property that are on scope, and trying to modify the value of that property every time when the watch gets executes like below

```
var app = angular.module('test', [])
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.val = 100;

  $scope.$watch('val',function(n,o){
     $scope.val= $scope.val+1;
  })

});
```

The above example creates a infinite digest loop. Normally digest loops gets executed for a maximum of 10 times and minimum of 2 times just to check if any property has been changed in the watch or not...basically it does a dirty checking

Comment: That's a problem, i've gone through common mistakes with watchers but i didn't event created watch (manually). The same in example, there is no $watch created manually and no changes i data.

Edit: to be precise there are watchers inside form-item component but this watch is assigned to specified key and that key is not changing. Problem is why that error appears only when state is loaded again and not when loaded for the first time.

Even if you remove that watchers error appears.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in `ng-include` directive which was dependent on variable from controller. Because when state changed ng-include couldn't find template it tried to load index.html and that caused a problem. Solution for that is to compile template manually inside component. Because component doesn't have `compile` as a directive has we need to change `$postLink()` and put compilation in it.

https://plnkr.co/edit/N2kUSCljMxaWTS7bZ2uC?p=preview

```
$element.contents().remove();
$templateRequest(templateUrl).then(function(html){
    var template = angular.element(html);
    var compiledContents = $compile(template);
    compiledContents($scope, function(clone){
         $element.append(clone);
    });
});
```

This solves a problem.